# Windows 11 Permission denied (publickey)

Tags: ssh

I have been unable to access servers via SSH after a recent upgrade to Windows 11.

I keep getting a `permission denied (publickey)` error.

I have tried regenerating new public keys with `ed25519` instead of the deprecated `rsa` and I still get the same error.

I have seen answers alluding to file permissions but am afraid am not sure what files they are referring to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked after recent updates on windows 11.

Answer (score -1):

The files that they are most likely referring to are typically the `.ssh` folder itself (this folder can be found in your home directory) and the contents within. Here's a table for recommended permissions on those files and folder.

| Element | Permission |
| --- | --- |
| .ssh directory | 700 ((drwx------) |
| public keys | 644 (-rw-r--r--) |
| private keys | 600 (-rw-------) |
| authorized_keys | 600 (-rw-------) |
| known_hosts | 600 (-rw-------) |
| config | 600 (-rw-------) |

You can read more about it at https://linuxhandbook.com/fix-permission-denied-publickey/.